# Android App crashes when adding Facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook

Whenever I try to run my app on simulation, I get the error message "Unfortunately, My App has stopped".

My MainActivity.java is the default one Android Studio gives when creating a project with a Blank Activity.

This is my the block for the button in content_main.xml

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

This is my error

```
12-29 14:49:37.660 8228-8228/com.tyler.mysimplefacebook E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.tyler.mysimplefacebook, PID: 8228

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tyler.mysimplefacebook/com.tyler.mysimplefacebook.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)                                                                              
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                              
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                              
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                          
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                              
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.tyler.mysimplefacebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                          at com.tyler.mysimplefacebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                          at com.tyler.mysimplefacebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                       Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
                                                                          at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:136)
                                                                          at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.<init>(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
                                                                          at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.<init>(LoginButton.java:561)
                                                                          at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:561)
                                                                          at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:66)
                                                                          at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:200)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                          at com.tyler.mysimplefacebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post your complete xml file and manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your parent layout : `xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

like

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"
    style="@style/com_facebook_loginview_default_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/connect_with_facebook"
    fb:login_text="@string/connect_with_facebook"
    fb:logout_text="Connecting with facebook" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to initialize the sdk as the error said --> Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()`

You need to add this line in your **onCreate(...)** method of your Activity:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```